# Print latex text based on if statement to make PDF

Tags: r, pdf, latex, markdown

I am creating a pdf report for people and would like to exclude some sections based on the results to make things easier for people (for example, no issues were found in this, so there is no need to explain something with a blank table).

I have tried an If statement within an R chunk and a eval='' statement as well in the header of the code chunk. It runs properly when I just include the table created by kableExtra; however, when I include the text I would like to explain this, it gives me multiple errors such as "\T" is an unrecognized escape in character string"

```
do_this = (nrow(tableone) >= 1)
```

```
print("message
 \begin{Form}
    \TextField[name = tableoneone, width = 10cm,
               height = 3cm,
               multiline=true]{}
\end{Form}  ")
```

I would like for this not to be included in the final document if it fails the check (number of rows in table one is zero). However, this is not the case. Is there something I'm doing wrong or some other way to do this that I am not thinking of?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by your use of backslashes in the character string. In R (and most other  modern languages), [backslashes in strings start an *escape sequence*](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html).

If you want to include a literal backslash, you need to double it up (`'\\'`).

Additionally, `print` isn’t the correct function to use here — `print` is a (somewhat poorly named) function to examine values *in interactive mode*. It should *never* be used in scripts. Instead, use `writeLines` or `cat` to output text to standard output or to a file, or `message` to create non-output messages.

```
cat("\\begin{Form}
    \\TextField[name = tableoneone, width = 10cm,
               height = 3cm,
               multiline=true]{}
\\end{Form}\n")
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I have tried it all with cat, writeLines, and Message, but I get "## [1] "TDH Notes: \n\\begin{Form}\n \\TextField[name = tableoneone, width = 10cm,\n" in the resulting pdf instead of the textfield box I am desiring. Is there another way?

Comment: The code chunk needs to have `results = 'asis'` for the latex to be interpreted as Latex code, not text. In other words, your code chunk header should look like `{r results = 'asis'}`.